# Retrieving value from combobox Winforms / Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, combobox

I am trying to populate my combobox with a list of companies and then get value of selected company (its `Id`) into my database.

I have this class `CBItem`:

```
public class CBItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return Name;
    }
}
```

I add items to combobox using this:

```
using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    var list_of_companies = db.Companies;

    foreach (Company c in list_of_companies)
    {
        CBItem item = new CBItem();
        item.Name = c.Name;
        item.Value = c.Id;
        comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Problem is when I want to get value of selected item, I have tried something like this:

```
new_person.Company.Id = (comboBox1.SelectedItem).Value;
```

Of course it doesn't work :/ Any tips?

Comment: What kind of "doesn't work"? Doesn't compile? Wrong value? Null?

Comment: From my understanding, I add objects of class CBItem to combobox list. These object should have property Name and Value which I should be able to use.

Comment: I get this info:
'object' does not contain definition of 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting the first argument of type 'object' could be found

Comment: You may need to cast the `object` returned by [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) to a `CBItem`

Comment: I have tried this:
new_person.Company.Id = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as CBItem).Value;
but I get:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: If you cast comboBox1.SelctedItem to CBItem, it should work. Are you sure that the null reference is not new_person.Company?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there is something wrong with this line:
`new_person.Company.Id`
I don't know what is wrong. I have model Person which has foreign key to company's id.
Maybe there si something wrong with my DB model.
My Person model:

```
public class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {

        }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Job { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public int Mobile { get; set; }

        public Company Company { get; set; }
    }
```

Company model:

```
public class Company
    {
        public Company()
        {

        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int NIP { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Person> Person { get; set; }
    }
```

Saving code:

```
using (var db = new DataContext())
            {
                Person new_person = new Person();
                new_person.Name = textBox1.Text;
                new_person.Surname = textBox2.Text;
                new_person.Job = textBox3.Text;
                new_person.Phone = Int32.Parse(textBox4.Text);
                new_person.Mobile = Int32.Parse(textBox5.Text);
                new_person.Company.Id = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as CBItem).Value;
                db.Person.Add(new_person);
                db.SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Person successfully added!");
                this.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine if:

- `new_person` is not `null`
- `new_person.Company` is not `null`
- `combobox.SelectedItem` is not `null`

Also you have to cast `combobox.SelectedItem` to `CBItem` like this:

```
new_person.Company.Id = ((CBItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Value;
```

---

As a site note instead of adding each item one by one you can archive the same thing by binding the ComboBox via its `DataSource` property to an object that implements the [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx) interface or an [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
comboBox1.DataSource = list_of_companies
    .Select(c => new CBItem {
        Name = c.Name,
        Value = c.Id
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Well, this worked for me: `new_person.Company = db.Companies.Find(((CBItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Value);`

Comment: This is not neccessary. Your code leads to querying the table in your database (or at least the cached representation of your table) for an entity where the id equals the id of the selected element in your ComboBox - but you have already the entity referenced in `comboBox1.SelectedItem`.
If you want to assign the entity to your object model you can try:
`new_person.Company = (CBItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;`